# Did the Buddha have unpleasant emotions?

Tags: defilements, aversion

Did the Buddha have unpleasant or negative emotions after his enlightenment? For some time I believed the Buddha only had what you would call pleasant or peaceful emotions. But as I learned that Buddha was still visited by Mara after enlightenment, I began to question this notion.

Furthermore, I read an Ajah Chah book in which he said the Buddha did have defilements, it is just that he was ‘far’ from them.

http://www.ajahnchah.org/book/Opening_Dhamma_Eye1.php

What are your thoughts on this?

I think if we cling too tightly to some ideal in which we never experience any sort of emotional discomfort, then this can actually be the cause of suffering as it causes aversion in us. Because if we wish to be free from these feelings we can prolong them by giving them too much attention instead of letting them simply pass.

May all beings be well.

Answer (score 2):

Unless Ajahn Chah used the term "Enlightened Ones" to refer to Stream-Enterer, Once-Returner & Non-Returner, he was mistaken, which I doubt. Keep in mind what is being read is a translation.

> The Buddha said that the Enlightened Ones were far from defilements.
> This doesn't mean that they ran away from defilements, they didn't run
> away anywhere. Defilements were there. He compared it to a lotus leaf
> in a pond of water. The leaf and the water exist together, they are in
> contact, but the leaf doesn't become damp. The water is like
> defilements and the lotus leaf is the Enlightened Mind.

The Buddha did not have unpleasant or negative emotions (sankhara; defilements) after enlightenment. The Buddha only experience painful sensations (vedana).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Mahaparinibbana Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html):

> And soon after the Blessed One had eaten the meal provided by Cunda
> the metalworker, a dire sickness fell upon him, even dysentery, and he
> suffered sharp and deadly pains. **But the Blessed One endured them
> mindfully, clearly comprehending and unperturbed**.

After Nibbana, the Buddha could indeed experience the sensation of pain (as he did in the case of dysentery), but he nevertheless does not suffer from it. Hence, suffering had indeed ended for the Buddha.

According to [Itivuttaka 44](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.2.028-049.than.html#iti-044):

> This was said by the Blessed One, said by the Arahant, so I have
> heard: "Monks, there are these two forms of the Unbinding property.
> Which two? The Unbinding property with fuel remaining, & the Unbinding
> property with no fuel remaining.
> Footnote
> And what is the Unbinding property with fuel remaining? There is the
> case where a monk is an arahant whose fermentations have ended, who
> has reached fulfillment, finished the task, laid down the burden,
> attained the true goal, ended the fetter of becoming, and is released
> through right gnosis. His five sense faculties still remain and, owing
> to their being intact, he is cognizant of the agreeable & the
> disagreeable, and is sensitive to pleasure & pain. His ending of
> passion, aversion, & delusion is termed the Unbinding property with
> fuel remaining.
>
> And what is the Unbinding property with no fuel remaining? There is
> the case where a monk is an arahant whose fermentations have ended,
> who has reached fulfillment, finished the task, laid down the burden,
> attained the true goal, ended the fetter of becoming, and is released
> through right gnosis. For him, all that is sensed, being unrelished,
> will grow cold right here. This is termed the Unbinding property with
> no fuel remaining."
>
> Commentary (Thanissaro):
> With fuel remaining (sa-upadisesa) and with no fuel
> remaining (anupadisesa): The analogy here is to a fire. In the first
> case, the flames are out, but the embers are still glowing. In the
> second, the fire is so thoroughly out that the embers have grown cold.
> The "fuel" here is the five aggregates (see the Glossary). While the
> arahant is still alive, he/she still experiences the five aggregates,
> but they do not burn with the fires of passion, aversion, or delusion.
> When the arahant passes away, there is no longer any experience of
> aggregates here or anywhere else.

After attaining Nibbana, but being still alive, the Arahant or Buddha still could experience the sensations of pain because the five aggregates are still operating. But he will not suffer from it, or have passion, aversion and delusion. Meanwhile, after death, the five aggregates no longer operate anywhere.

In any case, suffering ends completely after Nibbana. The Buddha does not suffer from disease, although he may experience it.

Answer (score 0):

When Buddha was about to die , he was very sick. He was in pain but he followed his practice and was aware of the Dhammas arising in him like painful feeling.
His pain was mitigated due to his meditation practice.

We need to give attention to what arises whether body , perception, feelings, choices , consciousness but we should discard them as they are not me , mine or myself. There is no lust or aversion or delusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some mild evidence to infer an arhant feels unpleasant emotions:

FROM [DN16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin):

> Now at that time a monk named Subhadda, who had gone forth when old,
> was sitting in that assembly. He said to those mendicants, “**Enough,
> reverends, do not grieve or lament.** We’re well rid of that Great
> Ascetic. And we are oppressed: ‘This is allowable for you; this is not
> allowable for you.’ Well, now we shall do what we want and not do what
> we don’t want.”
>
> Then Venerable Mahākassapa addressed the mendicants, “**Enough,
> reverends, do not grieve or lament.** Did the Buddha not prepare us
> for this when he explained that we must be parted and separated from
> all we hold dear and beloved? How could it possibly be so that what is
> born, created, conditioned, and liable to wear out should not wear
> out, even the Realized One’s body?”

Although it does not depict an arhant in particular, one can assume some of that gathering were indeed realized ones.  That being the case, perhaps Buddha himself experienced some unpleasantness too.

On a side note, I think Subhadda, seeming hard-nosed, was probably trying to create a diversion for some other monks - he even praises his teacher [here](https://suttacentral.net/tha-ap51/en/walters?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false).

Answer (score -1):

This is an invalid question. Buddha is not some entity that owns the skandhas, so we cannot speak of Buddha "having" emotions, either positive or negative. Buddha is not one of the skandhas so Buddha is not (identified with) emotions. Therefore, if negative emotions do occur, they have nothing to do with Buddha.